# How do I get the sum of my parameters so I can assign it to a variable?

Tags: python, parameters, sum

```
import string
import secrets
import random

def password_gen(num_letters, num_digits, num_special_char):
    password_length = num_letters + num_digits + num_special_char #Better way to do this?
    password = []
    
    print("Welcome to Password Generator, your desired password length is", password_length)
    print("Your password will now be generated...")

    for i in range(num_letters):
        password.append(secrets.choice(string.ascii_letters))
    for i in range(num_digits):
        password.append(secrets.choice(string.digits))
    for i in range(num_special_char):
        password.append(secrets.choice(string.punctuation))

    random.shuffle(password)
      
    print("Your generated password is", "".join(password))

password_gen(6, 1, 3)
```

Tried using zip() and sum() but was given TypeErrors such as 'unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple''

Comment: Why do you think there is a better way? Is the number of param going to change in the future? If not, this is almost as readable as it can get. I anything, I would search for a replacement for the loops.

Comment: Your current approach is actually the most straightforward and efficient way to calculate the total password length.

Comment: @DeepSpace Ok thanks, could you explain why the loops are inefficient? I'm new as I'm sure you can tell, what would you recommend looking at instead?

Comment: @SashSinha Ok thanks for your time, appreciated.

Comment: There's really no need to sum the options beforehand – you could just print everything at the end with `len(password)`...

Comment: @AKX Ok makes sense, don't know why I couldn't think of that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use `sum((num_letters, num_digits, num_special_char))` -- you have to put them in an iterable to use `sum()`.